# AVPlayerViewController using audio-only AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avkit

Just starting out with AVKit, and I'm trying to play some audio.  It would be nice to use the new AVPlayerViewController detailed in [Mastering Modern Media Playback](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#503) so that I have a ready-made play/pause/seek UI.  I basically have a storyboard with a container view which has an embed segue to the AVPlayerViewController.  Then I use:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "embedAudio") {
        var playerViewController:AVPlayerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as AVPlayerViewController

        playerViewController.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "http://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/files.serialpodcast.org/sites/default/files/podcast/1420057326/serial-s01-e01.mp3"))
    }
}
```

It embeds nicely and plays, but it has a big black QuickTime symbol where the video would be.  I'm wondering if there's a way to make it look more like the Music or Podcasts app.

Answer (score 13):

Why reinvent the wheel?  Just use `AVPlayerViewController`'s `contentOverlayView` property.  Here you can set an album artwork image, or place any `UIView` between the QuickTime logo (where the video would be), and the controls.

Note that you must do this after the `AVPlayerViewController` has been presented, as its `contentOverlayView` property will be nil in `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score 9):

Do not use the **AVPlayerViewController**, as it is a full screen, black box, video player.

Instead, create your own view controller with, say, a toolbar and controls readily available in the OS (play, pause, stop, etc.) and hook them to your `AVAudioPlayer`. This is what the code of your very own view controller may look like:

**Maintain an instance of the player**

```
var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!
@IBOutlet weak var playProgress: UIProgressView!
```

**Example: Play**

```
@IBAction func doPlayAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioRecorder.url)
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch {}
}
```

**Example: Stop**

```
@IBAction func doStopAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let audioPlayer = self.audioPlayer {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
}
```

**Example: Track progress**

```
func playerProgress() {
    var progress = Float(0)
    if let audioPlayer = audioPlayer {
        progress = ((audioPlayer.duration > 0)
            ? Float(audioPlayer.currentTime/audioPlayer.duration)
            : 0)
    }
    playProgress.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
}
```

---

I have posted a **recording** and **playback** example using the methodology outlined in this answer.

[image: Preview]

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-32342486).