# Blocking default player to play audio files ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer

My App has functionality to record and play audio using `AVAudioRecorder/AVAudioPlayer` respectively. Whenever I download an audio file from the server, the file is opened automatically using the default player with a black screen as shown:

[image]

However, I actually have my own user interface to play audio files. How can I block this option programmatically?

Comment: Please add code showing how you download and open the audio file currently.

Comment: Are you using `AVPlayerViewController`, perhaps?

This may be useful...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402521/avplayerviewcontroller-using-audio-only-avplayer

Comment: I meant before opening or Initiating the AVAudioPlayer, Once downloaded the audio file content from server, this screen is opening.

Comment: I have not tried to open the audio file, i just downloaded in to local path with format of .wav

Comment: Please add code snippet showing how you download and open the audio file. Most likely, that's where your issue is.

Comment: Audio Player Initialisation : `self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL] error:&error];
 [self.audioPlayer setMeteringEnabled:YES];
  self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;`

Comment: Download Operation : Im just storing received audio file content inside document directory.